# Antlr 4 TEXT and DIGIT together

Tags: java, antlr4

I am parsing a SQL like language and I have problems with strings that starts with a number:

SELECT 90userN  is parsed to SELECT 90 AS userN

Since I remove the whitespaces, it somehow gets the digits as the name and the string as the alias.

I don't know even where to start.

Grammar:

```
result_column  :    '*'                             
            |       table_name '.' '*'                  
            |       table_name '.' any_name             
            |       expr                                


any_name :      keyword
            |   IDENTIFIER
            |   STRING_LITERAL
            |   '(' any_name ')'
    ;

    expr:   literal_value;

literal_value : 
                NUMERIC_LITERAL
            |   STRING_LITERAL
            |   DATE_LITERAL
            |   IDENTIFIER
            |   NULL
;

IDENTIFIER :    
          '"' (~'"' | '""')* '"'
        | '`' (~'`' | '``')* '`'
        | '[' ~']'* ']'
        | [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
STRING_LITERAL : '\'' ( ~'\'' | '\'\'' )* '\'' ;
NUMERIC_LITERAL : 
    DIGIT+ ( '.' DIGIT* )? ( E [-+]? DIGIT+ )?
    | '.' DIGIT+ ( E [-+]? DIGIT+ )? ;
DATE_LITERAL:   DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT;
```

Comment: Would be a good start to post some source code. Crystal balls are expensive these days.

Comment: added the part of the grammaer

Comment: IT seems that the way in which you "remove the white space" is incorrect. In any case, 90userN is not a string in your grammar; it's actually a syntax error - neither an identifier nor a number

Comment: It translated to SELECT 90 userN which is valid syntax
So how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers in SQL can not start with numbers and that is really clear in the last alternative of your `IDENTIFIER` rule: `[a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*;`

I think you are already using it, but refer to the [SQLite4 grammar example](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sqlite/SQLite.g4)